# Does anyone use the "swingx" extensions to Swing?

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I've seen "swingx" mentioned and referred to here.

However, every time I try to visit the site:

http://swinglabs.org/

It's down! Is this still an active, viable project? Or is it outdated and abandoned?

Comment: Answering the title question: I do!

Answer (score 10):

the assumed dead are most likely to live on:
[announcement of SwingX 1.6](http://www.dzone.com/links/swingx_16_released.html) And as one the owners of the project, I can assure you that it's very much alive and very much kicking.

**Update Aug. 2012**

And still alive and kicking, [current version is 1.6.4](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/swinglabs/swingx-164-released)

Comment: Can I also contribute to SwingX in some way ? +1, and congrats for touching the 15K mark :-)

Comment: sure, easiest: use it, test it, report issues, contribute opinion/criticisme/praise/patches/ideas :-) The (low traffic) forum is http://www.java.net/forums/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/swinglabs?force=302 Thanks!

Comment: Please put it on github, we need an alternate source of download. I would like to execute the demo, but I can't find it anymore. We have a big project using SwingX.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [SwingLabs SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) project page, the project is still active and, actually, the project team seems to be preparing the release of [Swingx 1.6](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=66444&tstart=0) so it doesn't look like dead.

Answer (score 2):

I use it.

It's down now (Sun Sep 20 20:04:37 CDT 2009) because "Maximum Connections Reached: 4096 -- Retry later" I'm guessing too many people use it. The swingx subproject page is up though https://swingx.dev.java.net/. I must say that swinglabs has never, until now, been down for me. It has always been very slow, but never unreachable.

Swingx recently went to 1.0. People sing java 1.5 should not expect further updates and swinglab's effort is going to be placed in unifying their sorting/filtering with java 1.6 sorting/filtering.

Answer (score 2):

you can check [this link](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) which contains the statement:

> Important note: SwingX 1.0 is the last release targeted at Java 5 (JDK 1.5, "Tiger"). Immediately after the release, the codebase was - in fact, still is - moved to target Java 6 (JDK 1.6, "Mustang").

the recent activity on [the forum](http://forums.java.net/jive/forum.jspa?forumID=73) indicates that there are in fact many current users.

Comment: @akf: I don't think that moving to Java 6 (and hence requiring it in client code) is in the least bit surprising.  People cannot expect new development work to continue for a version of Java that is now 3+ (?) years out of date.  Getting "left behind" is the penalty you pay for not porting your code in a timely fashion.

Comment: @Stephen C  One of the main reasons AFAIK is to eliminate/unify swingx filtering/sorting with java 6 filtering/sorting. It causes a lot of confusion since JXTable/etc inherit from swing classes but the swing sorting/filtering does not work on the swingx classes. W/o this fundamental API change, swingx might still be targeting 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Swinglabs website has been down at least since july (google "swinglabs down") Despite the assurances here, I will assume it's dead and move on.

Comment: Sun's websites are all horrible and slow. It's better not to draw conclusions from them about the state of some open source project. I think SwingX is doing better than what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

"Each HTTP listener has an associated connection queue where requests that are waiting to be serviced are placed. The requests are taken out of the queue and serviced by one of the available processing threads. As expected, as the number of requests waiting to be serviced increases, the response times for those requests also increase. Additionally, the server will reject new requests if the number of items in the queue has reached a maximum configured value (default is 4096). The various parameters that can be configured for the connection queue and their default values are given below":

http://blogs.oracle.com/binublog/entry/glassfish_tuning_http_connection_queue